# Do signed cookies increase security if entire site is served over ssl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, cookies

Using Rails, I'm working through a tutorial where the author advocates storing a user id with: `cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id`

It seems sensible enough, but I'm curious: Does this actually increase the security of my site if the whole thing is served over ssl?

It's my understanding that cookies are encrypted along with all other response content. How would a signed cookie improve matters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Signed cookies protect you against a malicious *client* manipulating the value, not just an intermediary.

No matter how secure your SSL connection is, [without signed cookies] there's nothing to stop me changing my local browser cookie to contain `user_id=1`. A lot of the time that's not a big problem because the application can treat cookie values as untrusted, but signing instead means they *can* be trusted: the only way the client can have gotten that value is if the server previously sent it.

Comment: To add to this good answer, OP, please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862854/cookie-security-when-passed-over-ssl) which also sheds some more light on the subject.